# regex emails separated with slashes

Tags: regex

How do I make sure all the emails is separated with slashes in html pattern? Below is what I have so far. (Regex novice here)

`^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+[/]{1,4}$`

Currently:

- `abc@abc.com,abc@abc.com` false
- `abc@abc.com/def@def.com` false
- `abc@abc.com/aaa@aaa.com/` false
- `abc@abc.com/` true

My goals:

- `abc@abc.com,abc@abc.com` false
- `abc@abc.com/def@def.com` true
- `abc@abc.com/aaa@aaa.com/` false
- `abc@abc.com/` false
- `abc@abc.com` true

Comment: why `abc@abc.com/` is true and `abc@abc.com/aaa@aaa.com/` is false?

Comment: Your regexp has `[/]{1,4}$` at the end. So it requires 1 to 4 slashes at the end of the string. It doesn't allow them in the middle. Why do you allow more than one slash?

Comment: my guess is they meant they have `^([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+[/]){1,4}$` (note the parens around everything but the 1-4 quantifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a quantified group to allow any number (including 0) of emails followed by `/` at the beginning, and then a single email at the end.

```
^(?:[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+\/)*[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rT6eG7/1)

If you only want to allow 1-4 emails, change the `*` to `{0,3}`. This is only 0-3 because it only counts the 3 emails with `/` after them, not the email at the end.

To limit the total size, you can use a lookahead at the beginning:

```
^(?=.{0,320}$)(?:[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+\/)*[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]+$
```